# Fetch tweets using multiple operator

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to fetch Twitter feeds using more than 2 keywords, "Honda" and "YouTube".

Below is my code:

```
library(twitteR)
tweets <- searchTwitter('honda+facebook', n=1500, lang="en")
```

First, is this the right way of using multiple operators to fetch tweets that involve the two terms?

Second, the code returned 1000+ tweets, but I've noticed many of them are very similar or exactly the same like below:

```
[409] "@astramotor Honda All New CB150R Quantum Red #CumadiASTRAMOTOR #ASMOQuiz *21"                                                                                           
[410] "@astramotor Honda All New CB150R Quantum Red #CumadiASTRAMOTOR #ASMOQuiz *20"                                                                                           
[411] "@astramotor Honda All New CB150R Quantum Red #CumadiASTRAMOTOR #ASMOQuiz *19"                                                                                           
[412] "@astramotor Honda All New CB150R Quantum Red #CumadiASTRAMOTOR #ASMOQuiz *18"                                                                                           
[413] "@astramotor Honda All New CB150R Quantum Red #CumadiASTRAMOTOR #ASMOQuiz *17"
```

Is there any way to eliminate these repetitive tweets?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: Yes, that is how you seperate the terms if you are looking for tweets that have "Honda" or "Facebook".

As for your second question, the [Twitter Search API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) says that you can put in negative terms by adding a '-' in front of the search term.